# ListView full button disappears

Tags: android, xml, button

I have a listview and a button in a layout file which looks fine, however if the listView fills the screen the button goes missing, can someone advise me please.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
 android:id="@+id/myListView"
 android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
 android:layout_height = "wrap_content"/>

 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/back_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dip"
    android:text="@string/backButton_label" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is it simply pushed off of the screen? What happens when you put the button above the list?

Comment: I would imagine it will stay on the screen but that will look ugly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping both the `ListView` and `Button` in their own `LinearLayout` each of which has a height of 0dp and a weight as a fraction of the total layout height.

Example, the following will give the `ListView` 90% of the layout and the `Button` 10%. Adjust values accordingly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
      android:id="@+id/myListView"
      android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
      android:layout_height = "fill_parent"/>
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button 
      android:id="@+id/back_button"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="20dip"
      android:text="@string/backButton_label" />
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```